# Linux laptop doesn't stay suspended when docking station connected

Tags: linux, linux-mint, thunderbolt, suspend

I have a laptop with Linux Mint installed, the power settings are set to suspend after 30min both on battery and charger. I've also set the `suspend to be performed when an external monitor is attached` flag in the settings.

Now, when the laptop is on its own, meaning without any docking station connected the suspend works just fine. Both, after 30min and lid closed, trigger the suspend.
However, when I connect my docking station via thunderbolt 3 to the laptop the suspend is not working any longer. The laptop will still not suspend even after hours. When closing the lid, then the laptops suspends shortly (~3 seconds) and then comes back up again.

What I've tried so far is to change the following setting values in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to:

```
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

but that didn't help.

System details:

- Linux Mint 20.1
- Kernel 5.4.0-77-generic

Docking station:

- Caldigit TS3+

Comment: You're saying that it _does_ suspend on lid close -- so the "suspend" settings are doing their job just fine. The actual problem is that it _wakes up_ on its own, and that's caused by something entirely different than your desktop environment.

Comment: @user1686 Only the lid close works for a couple of seconds but not the actual suspend after 30min

Comment: So what would be the cause for the wake up? I suspect the docking station is doing something funky...

Comment: Can you check with `sudo evemu-record` or `sudo libinput debug-events` to see if the dock just repeatedly spams the system with e.g. ghost keypresses?

Comment: @user1686 None of them show any activity from the dock